# RAILS - CHANGE FIELD OF ANOTHER TABLE - BOOLEAN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good afternoon. I'm new to rails and I'm using google translate to post in English here, so sorry if it's not very readable.

My question is, I have a User table, and a Setting table.

They are related (but I don't know if the relationship is correct), they can even confirm me, and I would like to know if:
when creating a user, I would like to automatically change the "email" and "push" fields of that user's settings table to true.
Would it be possible via a method that in the user model called: "setting_default"?

- User model.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :setting

   before_save :setting_default

   def setting_default
     self.setting.update(:email, 'true')
     self.setting.update(:push, 'true')
   end
```

- Setting Model

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :user
end
```

The Controller is normal, if you need it, I can put it in the post

My migration:

```
class CreateSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :settings do |t|
      t.boolean :email, default: true
      t.boolean :push, default: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end


class AddSettingsToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_reference :users, :setting, null: true, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

[image: database-setting-user]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google translate has worked well for you here.

First off you'll want to change your `Setting` model to belong to the `User`:

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Your `settings` DB table is missing a `user_id` field to tie the setting back to the user. I'm not used to the `add_reference` technique so I just do things myself in the migrations. This would work:

```
class CreateSettings < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :settings do |t|
      t.integer :user_id

      t.boolean :email, default: true
      t.boolean :push, default: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

(Make note that your `users` DB table has a field `setting_id` that it does not need. I don't think it should be there. I would remove it. Unless it's a Rails 6 thing I'm not used to.)

Next it would probably be better to assign the values if the save succeeds (and not if it fails) so you'll want an `after_save` instead. And I'm simplifying your value assignment just in case you're having an issue there:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_one :setting

   after_save :setting_default

   def setting_default
     setting.email = true
     setting.push = true
     setting.save(validate: false)
   end
   private :setting_default
```

And to answer what seems to be your question, yes, what you're trying to do should be easily possible. This is a very common thing to do. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

When you use one-to-one association you need to choose `has_one` in one and `belongs_to` in another model

Semantically user has one setting, but not setting has one user

So it's better to reverse them

To change your schema you need to write new migration

```rb
class ChangeOneToOneDirection < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    change_table :settings do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, foreign_key: true, null: false
    end

    User.where.not(setting_id: nil).find_each |user|
      Setting.find(user.setting_id).update_columns(user_id: user.id)
    end

    change_table :users do |t|
      t.remove :setting_id
    end
  end

  def down
    add_reference :users, :setting, null: true, foreign_key: true

    Setting.find_each do |setting|
      User.find(setting.user_id).update_columns(setting_id: setting.id)
    end

    change_table :settings do |t|
      t.remove :user_id
    end
  end
end
```

After migration you can change User model

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :setting

  after_commit :setting_default

  private

  def setting_default
    setting&.update(email: true, push: true)
  end
end
```

It's better to update associated model only if saves are in the database. And user can haven't setting. That's why `after_commit` and safe-navigator `&`